# Frontend page doesn't display unless i comment out my table making code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, package.json

Here is my code. I used typescript and my database is in a .json file. My page displays fine when I don't try to display the table and disappears completely

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./viewAvailableShifts.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import MockData from "./data.json";

export class ViewAvailableShifts extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const [data] = useState(MockData);

        return (
            <>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="leftcolumn">
                        <div className="center">
                            <h1>Available Shifts</h1>
                            <div>
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <th>First Name</th>
                                        <th>Last Name</th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {data.map((d) => (
                                            <tr key={d.id}>
                                                <td>{d.first_name}</td>
                                                <td>{d.last_name}</td>
                                                <td>{d.email}</td>
                                                <td>{d.gender}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        ))}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mapping the table rows outside of the return? Also wondering why data was in square brackets? Maybe curley braces or none at all, depending on how you return it from state? so if it's already an array just data if you need to make it an array maybe spread [...data]?

```
export class ViewAvailableShifts extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = useState(MockData)

    const rows = data.map((d) => (
      <tr key={d.id}>
        <td>{d.first_name}</td>
        <td>{d.last_name}</td>
        <td>{d.email}</td>
        <td>{d.gender}</td>
      </tr>
    ))

    return (
      <>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="leftcolumn">
            <div className="center">
              <h1>Available Shifts</h1>
              <div>
                <table>
                  <thead>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is bigger than just declaring and calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks doesn't work inside class component

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./viewAvailableShifts.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import MockData from "./data.json";

export const ViewAvailableShifts = () => {
        const [data] = useState(MockData);

        return (
            <>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="leftcolumn">
                        <div className="center">
                            <h1>Available Shifts</h1>
                            <div>
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <th>First Name</th>
                                        <th>Last Name</th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {data.map((d) => (
                                            <tr key={d.id}>
                                                <td>{d.first_name}</td>
                                                <td>{d.last_name}</td>
                                                <td>{d.email}</td>
                                                <td>{d.gender}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        ))}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish with useState? useState is a hook that listens for changes to `data` and then changes the UI accordingly. Use state returns two values though, it would be used like this...

```
const [data, setData]= useState(someDataOrEmptyValueButNeverActuallyEmpty)

onSomeEvent((eventOrDataOrWhatNot) => setData(eventOrDataOrWhatNot))
```

and then whatever in your UI that was depending on `data` will adjust to the new values.

Answer (score 0):

So, are you ready?
You can't us hooks in class components

```
export const ViewAvailableShifts = () => {
        const [data] = useState(MockData);
‏}
```

Should be

```
export default class ViewAvailableShifts extends Component {
   constructor() {
   super();
   this.state: {data: MockData}
   }
render(){...}
}
```